# How to only target a single item in a UI rendered list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am building a simple todo-esk feature where if a user clicks the edit icon, only that item is editable. I implement this currently with a useState hook, `const [editingMemberName, setEditingMemberName] = useState(false)`, but when I call a function, `editMemberName` all instances of items show an input field. This is not the experience I am going for.

Here are some screen shots that should make this more clear:
[image]

[image]

As you can see, I have two cards, but when I click the tool icon, both input boxes are displayed.

Here is the code:

```js
const [editingMemberName, setEditingMemberName] = useState(false)
const [memberName, setMemberName] = useState('')

const handleChangeName = (e) => {
    setMemberName(e.target.value)
  }
// Update member name
const editMemberName = async (e) => {
    setEditingMemberName(true)
  }


const memberItems = members.map((member) => {
  return (
  <div
        key={member.id}
      >
        <div className="flex items-center gap-4 w-full">
          {editingMemberName ? (
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Johnny Appleseed"
              onChange={handleChangeName}
            />
          ) : (
            <>
              <div>
                {member.name}
              </div>
              <h3>{member.name}</h3>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          {editingMemberName ? (
            <button
              onClick={() => updateMemberName(member.id)}
            >
              <CgCheckO size=".75em" />
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button
              onClick={() => editMemberName(member.id)}
            >
              <FiTool size=".75em" />
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
)
```

I've realized that editingMemberName hook operates on all instances, but I am not sure how to only target a single item.

Note: you can assume that the members array has a unique id for each item.

```js
members: [
 {
   name: "Johnny",
   id: 123
 },
{
   name: "George",
   id: 456
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are referring the boolean to all the boxes and not an individual element, use

```
const [editingMemberName, setEditingMemberName] = useState(members.map(e => false))
```

Something along the lines

```
const editMemberName = async (memberID, index) => {
let new_editing_members_state = members.map(e => false)
new_editing_members_state[index] = true
    setEditingMemberName(new_editing_members_state)
}
```

```
const memberItems = members.map((member, index) => {
  return (
  <div
        key={member.id}
      >
        <div className="flex items-center gap-4 w-full">
          {editingMemberName ? (
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Johnny Appleseed"
              onChange={handleChangeName}
            />
          ) : (
            <>
              <div>
                {member.name}
              </div>
              <h3>{member.name}</h3>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          {editingMemberName[index] ? (
            <button
              onClick={() => updateMemberName(member.id)}
            >
              <CgCheckO size=".75em" />
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button
              onClick={() => editMemberName(member.id,index)}
            >
              <FiTool size=".75em" />
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
)
```